# Rails: How to let user input define how many entries are recorded into the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I am developing a web application where a user inserts inventory of shoes. So the user enters style code, size, price, and quantity. I want quantity to define how many entries there are in the database. So, if the quantity is three, three separate rows would be created for each shoe. Currently each form submission creates one row in the database.

My create in my shoe_controller:

```
def create
    @shoe = Shoe.new(shoe_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shoe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shoe, notice: 'Shoe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shoe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shoe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: shoe, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if shoe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(shoe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shoe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% shoe.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :sku %>
    <%= form.text_field :sku %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :size %>
    <%= form.text_field :size %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :quantity %>
    <%= form.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :price %>
    <%= form.text_field :price %>
  </div>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What changes would I need to make to achieve the result I am looking for?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rohit is correct in that using the `Shoe.create` method will get you what you want. But to implement this, you can change your controller to the following. I'm sure there are much cleaner ways of doing this, but it *should* get you what you're looking for. Also, I would suggest validating the quantity in shoe_params is a positive integer.

```
def create
 @show = Show.new(shoe_params)

 # This will create an array of shoes from your params
 new_shoes = (1..shoe_params[:quantity]).collect { Shoe.new(shoe_params) }

 # Save each record and put the result in an array
 success = new_shoes.map(&:save)

 if success.all?
  # all records saved
 else
  # maybe @shoe.valid? is false or something else happened
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. For this to work would I need to create a save method in my controller. I am getting an undefined method `save' for #<ActionController: error.

Comment: Never mind. I was able to resolve the problem (just a typo). Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, the save method wasn't working before because collect was returning an array of hashes and not Shoe records. I updated it but couldn't comment since I didn't have enough rep. Glad it's working though!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ActiveRecord::Persistence#create`, which can accept an array of hashes as a parameter.

Suppose quantity is three, so build the 3 new hash which will contain your records.

```
  shoes_params = [
    {
      code: 1,
      size: 8,
      price: 300,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      code: 1,
      size: 8,
      price: 300,
      quantity: 1
    }, ...
  ]


Shoe.create(shoes_params)
```

Comment: Would I need to code this in the controller or the model?

Comment: I'm still confused. Can you please explain in more detail how to implement this. I am very new to Ruby and Web development.

Comment: please have a look https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html in this link you will get an idea. Let me know if it helps you or not?

Comment: I am still sadly confused. I made my create action in the controller just this line:    Shoe.create([{sku: "AMR",size: 10,price: 1000}]). But this does not add this row to my database.

Comment: what is the error, can you please paste it here so I can help you out

Comment: There is no error, it simply does not modify the database at all. Not sure if this matters, but I made the shoes model and controller using scaffolding.

Comment: (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/shoes_controller.rb:30
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/shoes_controller.rb:30
No template found for ShoesController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Comment: so these error is not related to creating the records. Can you please try this simple query in rails console?

Comment: What simple query do you want me to try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547249/creating-multiple-entries-on-one-model-ruby-on-rails-non-nested?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: I have the same exact problem as this person, do you know if there is a simpler solution to this?